# In AngularJS, jquery append method seems not to be working in directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to implement my own version of ng-repeat. But somehow I cannot get it working since the jquery append method seems not to be working.

**script.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("myRepeat", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var c = element.children()[0];
      console.log(c)
      for(var i=0; i<attrs.times; i++) {
        element.append(c);
      }
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).click(function() {
          console.log("hi");
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**index.html:**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <my-repeat times="5"><p>hello world</p></my-repeat>
</body>
```

[Code in use at plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Plxmm7u7AOOfyZQk9ig?p=preview).

Comment: I edited your post, but for next time; please post your code on SO aswell, we shouldn't have to go to another page just to read your code. For example it's handy to have the code available on the same page you're writing an answer etc.

Comment: Will do. Thanks timss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after reading a bit of code of jquery. Append will check and remove duplicate when appending DOM element. I packed `c` into a dom list and changed the append line in my for-loop into:

```
element.append(c.clone());
```

And the problem is gone.